# Making different Tornado servers serve different pages

Tags: webserver, integration, tornado, backend, haproxy

Let's say I have two Tornado servers, `server1` for serving web pages with pattern `/news/blahblah`, and `server2` for pages with pattern `/data/blahblah`. These two servers together form the back-end of my application.

I wonder how should I integrate and expose them to the clients, so that different requests to different URLs get served by different server.

I heard of HAProxy, do I have to use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use haproxy, but you don't need it in this case.

Use nginx.

Here is example of config for multiple tornados:

```
server {
    listen *:80;  
    server_name myserver.com;  

    location /data/blahblah {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /news/blahblah { 
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

And then you can scale it with haproxy...

```
listen http 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats refresh 10s
    stats hide-version
    cookie MYSERVER insert
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option httpchk OPTIONS /heath.html
    option forwardfor
    option httplog
    option logasap
    log global
    server MYSERVER 10.0.0.1:80 cookie SERVER1 check
    server MYSERVER 10.0.0.2:80 cookie SERVER2 check
    server MYSERVER 10.0.0.3:80 cookie SERVER3 check
```